# Can I ask a Code Review question about a Linux kernel patch made by someone else?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I've been following another developer who fixed a bug in the Linux kernel. The developer has posted a patch series hoping it would get reviewed/merged, but he got no response so far. The patches have been out for a while.

I'm no expert kernel developer, but I have a feeling that his patch could be improved.

More context: The bug that needs fixing is a rather simple one, but his approach to fix it involves creating a new function for memory allocation in the kernel, which I suspect is overkill.

Would it be on topic for this site to post such a question about code of which I'm not the author?

Comment: Please see: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3654/29371

Comment: And: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/why-is-only-my-own-written-code-on-topic